# Creating a child process of a bash file in node

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, unix, child-process

Below I have a string with newlines line, this string is the contents of a bash file. I was wondering if there was a way to run this contents without creating the bash file. I would like to do something like below, where I just pipe the contents to the `sh` command. But this blew up with the error below.

```
let string = "\necho \'hello-world\'\n"

execAsync(`${string} | sh`)
```

I know I can create a temp file / exec it with the path equal to the current working dir / delete the file. But I'd rather not go through the trouble if there's a way to run the script without creating a file.

Error:

```
{ Error: Command failed: 
echo 'hello-world'
 | sh
/bin/sh: -c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
/bin/sh: -c: line 2: ` | sh'

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:207:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:852:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:492:12)
  cause: 
   { Error: Command failed: 
   echo 'hello-world'
    | sh
   /bin/sh: -c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
   /bin/sh: -c: line 2: ` | sh'

       at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:207:12)
       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:852:16)
       at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
       at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
       at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:492:12)
     killed: false,
     code: 2,
     signal: null,
     cmd: '\necho \'hello-world\'\n | sh' },
  isOperational: true,
  killed: false,
  code: 2,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '\necho \'hello-world\'\n | sh' }
```

Comment: `let string = "\necho \'hello-world\'"` -- you can't start a new line in a shellscript with `|`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the script contents to the shell through the `-c` option. It is supported by most shells.

Example:

```
var execAsync = require('exec-async');

let script = "echo \'hello\' $(whoami)\nls -l\necho 'bye'"

execAsync('sh', ['-c', script]).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```